Найти максимальное значение в массиве строк JS
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно найти максимальное значение в массиве из чисел и слов?
В коде ниже максимальное значение находит лишь от 0 до 9, а вот если цифра уже 10, то максимальное значение не находится:
let maxPassDir_7 =['text,2','text,5','text,9','text,10','text,19'];

let maxxPass_7 = getMaxValueP(maxPassDir_7);

function getMaxValueP(maxPassDir_7){

    let maxxPass_7 = maxPassDir_7[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < maxPassDir_7.length; i+=2) { 
        if (maxxPass_7 < maxPassDir_7[i])
            maxxPass_7 = maxPassDir_7[i];
    }

    return maxxPass_7; 
}

console.log(maxxPass_7 + ' Maximal Element'); // text,9 Maximal Element"


а массив точно правильно указан? там не должно быть случайно текст в кавычках, потом запятая а потом цифра без кавычек?

ну а если это реальный массив, то сравнение неправильное....и надо сравнивать не сами эти строки, а числа у этих строк.... для этого надо к ним применят split и брать число по индексу 1 от этого сплита, приводить к числу и только тогда их сраванивать

Массив правильный, он такой и нужен. Спасибо за подсказку со split !!

Вам нужно вывести максимальное значение вместе с текстом ("text,")? То есть вы ожидаете на выводе text,19?

Да, без текста я нашел как сделать, а вот с text, 19  ну никак не получается

Если вам нужно вывести максимальное значение вместе с текстом (text,), то в таком случае вам подойдёт этот код:
let maxPassDir_7 = ['text,2', 'text,5', 'text,9', 'text,10', 'text,19'];

let maxxPass_7 = getMaxValueP(maxPassDir_7);

function getMaxValueP(maxPassDir_7) {
    let maxxPass_7 = maxPassDir_7[0];
    let maxValue = parseInt(maxxPass_7.split(',')[1]);

    for (let i = 1; i < maxPassDir_7.length; i++) {
        let currentValue = parseInt(maxPassDir_7[i].split(',')[1]);
        if (maxValue < currentValue) {
            maxxPass_7 = maxPassDir_7[i];
            maxValue = currentValue;
        }
    }

    return maxxPass_7;
}

console.log(maxxPass_7 + ' Maximal Element'); // text,19 Maximal Element


Вот куда split нужно было ставить. Благодарю Вас!!!!!
